# Is there a way of using Spring JPA - JPQL instead of native query

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Normally, I try to use Spring JPA and JPQL instead of native query (Postgresql). However, I couldn't find any other solution and wrote sql code below. Because of subqueries in LEFT JOIN clauses, I can't use Spring JPA. Only subqueries in HAVING and WHERE clauses are allowed in Spring JPA and JPQL.

I can't separate this query into multiple queries. Because I use pagination and result should be ordered while getting data from database.

Also, I can't create views for this need and add logics in view sql, because there are some id parameters are used in subqueries and are dynamically sent by user via REST API.

Is there any other option to use Spring JPA and JPQL instead of native query for this example?

```
SELECT 
  CAST(ca.id as varchar) AS companyAddressId, 
  COALESCE(
    materialForecast.planningVolume, 
    0
  ) + COALESCE(
    componentForecast.planningVolume, 
    0
  ) AS planningVolume, 
  COALESCE(
    materialForecast.planningSpend, 
    0
  ) + COALESCE(
    componentForecast.planningSpend, 
    0
  ) AS planningSpend 
FROM 
  company_address ca 
  JOIN company c ON c.id = '3333' 
  AND ca.company_id = c.id 
  AND c.is_deleted = false 
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT 
      mf.company_address_id as mid, 
      COALESCE(
        SUM(
          mf.volume * fn_get_unit_multiplier(
            mf.volume_unit_id, '1111'
          )
        ), 
        0
      ) as planningVolume, 
      COALESCE(
        SUM(
          mf.price * fn_get_currency_exchange(
            mf.currency_unit_id, 
            '2222', 
            'FORECAST', 
            CAST(mf.volume_date || '-01' as date)
          )
        ), 
        0
      ) as planningSpend 
    FROM 
      material_forecast mf 
    WHERE 
      TO_DATE(mf.volume_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN TO_DATE (
        '2021-01-15T00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD'
      ) 
      AND TO_DATE(
        '2022-01-16T00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD'
      ) 
      AND mf.is_deleted = false 
      AND mf.company_address_id = ca.id 
    GROUP BY 
      mf.company_address_id
  ) materialForecast ON TRUE 
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT 
      cf.company_address_id as cid, 
      COALESCE(
        SUM (
          cf.volume * cs.net_weight_value * fn_get_unit_multiplier(
            cs.net_weight_unit_id, '1111'
          )
        ), 
        0
      ) as planningVolume, 
      COALESCE(
        SUM (
          cf.price * fn_get_currency_exchange(
            cf.currency_unit_id, 
            '2222', 
            'FORECAST', 
            CAST(cf.volume_date || '-01' as date)
          )
        ), 
        0
      ) as planningSpend 
    FROM 
      component_forecast cf 
      JOIN component_specification cs ON cs.id = cf.component_specification_id 
      AND cs.is_deleted = false 
    WHERE 
      TO_DATE(cf.volume_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN TO_DATE (
        '2021-01-15T00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD'
      ) 
      AND TO_DATE(
        '2022-01-16T00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD'
      ) 
      AND cf.is_deleted = false 
      AND cf.company_address_id = ca.id 
    GROUP BY 
      cf.company_address_id
  ) componentForecast ON TRUE 
WHERE 
  ca.is_deleted = false 
ORDER BY 
  COALESCE(
    materialForecast.planningVolume, 
    0
  ) + COALESCE(
    componentForecast.planningVolume, 
    0
  ) DESC
```

Comment: JPA doesn't support lateral joins, so therefore this Postgres query can't be directly mapped to JPQL.  But, you might be able to write it in JPQL a different way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Also, I added this part to the question description: "I can't separate this query into multiple queries. Because I use pagination and result should be ordered while getting data from database." I mean that I may find a solution without using LATERAL, but I need subqueries in LEFT JOIN again. It means that I have to use native query again :/

Comment: This query is huge, and you also have proprietary date functions in there like `TO_DATE()`.  From a modest glance, I'd suggest just keeping this as a native query.